# Give combinatoric argument for this equation

Tags: combinatorics

$$n{n-1 \choose 2}={n \choose 2}{(n-2)}$$
Give a conceptual
explanation of why this formula is true.

Comment: Tried turning it into latex by $ signs around, you can edit again by hitting the "edit" button if it did not end up the way you wanted it again.

Comment: Hint:  to choose three people out of $n$ I can choose one and then two more from the remainder, or I can first choose two and then one more from the remainder.

Comment: @lulu That's not the ways to choose three people out of $n$. This value is not $\binom{n}{3}$, it is $3\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  True.  I should have said "The ways to choose the Chair and two people for Vice Chair out of $n$".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is another "Do-my-homework" question with no shown effort to attempt a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose from $n$ students, you want to select $1$ student to clean the blackboard and $2$ students to clean the ground. There are $n$ ways to choose a student to clean the blackboard, and from the remaining students there are totally $\binom{n-1}{2}$ ways to select students to clean the ground. Therefore, the total # of ways
is
$$
n\binom{n-1}{2}
$$
Alternatively, you can first select $2$ students to clean the ground, which is $\binom{n}{2}$, and from the remaining $n - 2$ students, you select one to clean the blackboard. If you count this way, the total # of ways is $\binom{n}{2}(n-2)$ and it should be equal to $n\binom{n-1}{2}$ because you count the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a derivation:
$$ n \binom{n-1}{2} = \frac{n (n-1)!}{2!(n-3)!} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-3)!} = \frac{1}{2}(n-2)(n-1)n$$

$$ \binom{n}{2}(n-2) = \frac{n!(n-2)}{2!(n-2)!} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-3)!} = \frac{1}{2}(n-2)(n-1)n $$

So it follows that:

$$ n \binom{n-1}{2} = \binom{n}{2}(n-2) $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
n{n-1 \choose 2}&=\binom n1 \binom{n-1}{2} \tag {choose 1 then 2}\\[1ex]
&= \binom n2 \binom{n-2}{1} \tag {choose 2 then 1}\\[1ex]
&={n \choose 2}{(n-2)}
\end{align}$$